# firebaseui.js:formatted:9514 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EmailAuthProvider' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

i wanted to use the Firebase UI and i used it, It was working fine at the first time but broken

[image: This is the the error on my page]

But i don't think this has the problem because its the code from Firebase UI themself

This is the code I have in **index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    var config = {
      apiKey: "**************************",
      authDomain: "chat-77ca3.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://chat-77ca3.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "chat-77ca3",
      storageBucket: "chat-77ca3.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "312413147357"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
  <title>Chat</title>
  <script defer="defer" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script defer="defer" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script defer="" src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.3.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.3.0/firebaseui.css" />
  <script src="node_modules/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: 'loggedin.html',
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ]
    }
    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the javascript in **loggedin.html**

HTML not included

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  initApp = function() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var email = user.email;
        var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        var uid = user.uid;
        var phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
        var providerData = user.providerData;
        user.getIdToken().then(function(accessToken) {
          document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
          document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign out';
          document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
            displayName: displayName,
            email: email,
            emailVerified: emailVerified,
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            photoURL: photoURL,
            uid: uid,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            providerData: providerData
          }, null, '  ');
        });
      } else {
        document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
        document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign in';
        document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = 'null';
      }
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  initApp()
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: I think it's the white space between `<` and  `script` at the top of you second code block

Comment: You're missing an import for `firebase-auth`:   `<script defer="defer" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>`

Comment: @diouze its the typo from stackoverflow's prettier i don't have the space and thanks for the comment

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when put the auth code it says `Firebase: Firebase service named 'auth' already registered (app/duplicate-service).` so it might not need it but thank you